# Possible generalization of multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have got stuck with a problem related to the multivariate hypergeometric distribution. I pick $n$ balls from an urn containing a total of $N$ balls. Each ball is painted with (possibly multiple) coloured dots. Eventually I'd like to be able to deal with $p$ possible colours, but for the time being say $p=3$ and that the colours are red, green and blue. I have a big table with the total number of balls with each of the $2^p$ dot combinations.

I want to compute the joint probability for ending up with $k_r$ balls with a red dot, $k_g$ balls with a green dot and $k_b$ balls with a blue dot. To me it looks like the multivariate hypergeometric distribution but with overlapping ball categories. Has anyone seen this problem before? Could you please point me in a promising direction?

Comment: Did you at least take a look at [the wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution)? Not to mention all the other [Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=multivariate+hypergeometric+distribution&oq=multivariate+hypergeometric+distribution&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.336j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I did. I can only find examples when each ball belongs to a single colour category. I am trying to find related results when balls can belong to multiple categories.

Comment: The multivariate hypergeometric distribution allows us to compute the joint probability mass function for the $2^p$ category combinations but not, without some brute-force summation, the marginal probability mass function for the $p$ colour counts.

Comment: I see. Sorry I misunderstood your question. This is not an easy problem and at this point I don't have much to contribute.